# Modelica external functions: C versus C99

Tags: modelica

In Modelica it is possible to define external functions. 
Chapter 12.9 of the spec says C and Fortran77 are supported, 
C++ and Fortran90 might be supported in the future. 
Now I wonder which [versions of C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language#C99) are supported?

In particular I need the logarithmic gamma function which is available in C99, so I tried the following:

```
function lgamma "logarithmic gamma function"
  input Real u;
  output Real y;
external "C" y = lgamma(u);
end lgamma;
```

but it does not work, while powf works:

```
function powf "power function a^b"
  input Real a;
  input Real b;
  output Real y;
external "C" y = powf(a,b);
end powf;
```

This probably happens because powf is available in C while lgamma was introduced in C99. 
But is this a limitation of Modelica, Dymola or of my compiler? 
Is there a way to get C99 external functions to work? 
On the [Wikipedia list of C mathematical operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_operations) there are some more interesting function like error function erf and erfc, these would also be nice to have.

Comment: With Visual Studio 2013 Microsoft introduces a Community Edition that has extended functionality and also brings an extended Math library! All of the mentioned functions do now work, many more are available, see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\math.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only assume that C89/90 code compiles in a Modelica compiler. This is mainly concerning syntax though (if you use `Include` annotations or `Library="file.c"`).

The functions that are available mainly depend on the C library that your compiler links against. I guess Microsoft's C library does not contain `lgamma`, so it cannot be linked against.
On Linux/OpenModelica, the `lgamma` example does work as `libm` contains the function (it's compiling using c90 mode, but implicitly adding a `double lgamma(double)` declaration).

The `powf` example also compiles, but does not work correctly since your `external "C"` declaration states that it uses double precision floating point (and you cannot change this as of Modelica 3.2). `powf` will read half of a and use it as its first argument, then read the second half of a and use it as its second argument. b would be discarded. If you set the compiler flags to `std=c99`, the error is detected:

> powf.h:23:15: error: conflicting types for ‘powf’

Note that if you use Dymola on Windows, you are most likely using Visual Studio. In that case, there is no C99 support except the parts that were copied from C++.

Comment: Thank you for that comprehensive answer!

Comment: PS: I wanted to write more, but stackexchange allows editing for 5min only, so here is the second part of my answer: Thank you for that comprehensive answer! I do use Dymola with Visual Studio 2010 Express and you are right, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h` there is no definition for lgamma. I sent an email to the Dymola support asking how to use `MinGW` instead, I would like to try that just to see what happens...

Comment: Looks like C++11 will bring lgamma, tgamma, erf and erfc to C++ so maybe the next MS Visual Studio will support these.