# External Functions: Reference headers in C-script to compiled dll

Tags: modelica, dymola

Using Dymola 2017.

*Case A) Calling an external c-script*

I have had success implementing simple external c functions that have no “# include <-->” statements:

**Modelica Function:**

```
function chirp

  input Modelica.SIunits.AngularVelocity w_start;
  input Modelica.SIunits.AngularVelocity w_end;
  input Real A;
  input Real M;
  input Real t;
  output Real u "output signal";

  external "C" u=chirp(w_start,w_end,A,M,t)
    annotation(IncludeDirectory="modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/", Include="#include \"chirp.c\"");

end chirp;
```

**C-script:**

```
double chirp(double w1, double w2, double A, double M, double time)
{
  double res;
  res=A*cos(w1*time+(w2-w1)*time*time/(2*M));
    
  return res;
}
```

---

*Case B) Calling an external function in a .dll file*

I also have had success in calling external functions within a compiled dll:

**Modelica Function:**

```
function bessel_Jn
  "Bessel function of the 1st kind (regular cylindrical) of order n"

  extends Modelica.Icons.Function;

  input Integer n;
  input Real x;
  output Real y;

  external "C" y=gsl_sf_bessel_Jn(n,x) annotation(LibraryDirectory="modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/gsl-1.8/", Library="libgsl");

end bessel_Jn;
```

---

*Case C) Calling an external c-script which uses functions from an external .dll via headers*

What I want to do now is create a c function that does more interesting things. My current approach is to include header files in the c function that references the compiled dll (in this case a compiled version of the GNU scientific library). This example has the header (although it does not do anything for the moment).

**Modelica Function:**

```
function chirp

  input Modelica.SIunits.AngularVelocity w_start;
  input Modelica.SIunits.AngularVelocity w_end;
  input Real A;
  input Real M;
  input Real t;
  output Real u "output signal";

  external "C" u=chirp(w_start,w_end,A,M,t)
    annotation(LibraryDirectory="modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/gsl-1.8/", Library="libgsl",
               IncludeDirectory="modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/", Include="#include \"chirp.c\"");

end chirp;
```

**C-cript:**

```
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h> //<-- note the additional header

double chirp(double w1, double w2, double A, double M, double time)
{
  double res;
  res=A*cos(w1*time+(w2-w1)*time*time/(2*M));
  return res;
}
```

When attempting to call the function above the error indicates failure to translate and nothing else due to the existence of the header file. If the header file is commented out the function will run as expected.

Please let me know if you have any insight as to how to properly go about implementing this feature. Thank you.

---

For reference: The image below is the path to the external c-script and .dll.

**Wrong Path:** Note gsl header folder is within gsl-1.8 folder
[image: Resources Source Folder]

**Correct Path:** Note gsl header folder is at the same level as gsl-1.8 folder
[image: Corrected Resources Source Folder]

---

**UPDATE:** Header works but function call causes translation to fail

I have updated the c-script to now call a function that should be handeled by the header. In its current state it won't work. Perhaps it can't find the .dll file although its specified in the modelica code? Do I have to include a load .dll command in the c-scripts?

```
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

double chirp(double w1, double w2, double A, double M, double time)
{
  double res;
  double y;
  res=A*cos(w1*time+(w2-w1)*time*time/(2*M));
  y = gsl_sf_bessel_j0(time); // <-- Calls a function from the .dll file using the header
  return res;
}
```

Comment: I would have expected the last example to work (provided headers were located where I think they are). So probably either: file a bug report with Dymola (?) support or try it in another tool first to make sure.

Comment: @sjoelund.se I've added a picture to hopefully clarify what the folder structure looks like. Does this match what you expected or have I goofed?

Comment: @sjoelund.se I think I may have found a solution by changing the location of the gsl header folder. I'll update my post above. I swear I already tried it before but it's working now though so I must have changed something else.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. However, another solution would be use #include "gsl-1.8/gsl/gsl_errno.h" instead. The difference between <> and "" for include is that "" also searches relative to the source file - which may be seen as chirp.c (so people normally use <> for system files and "" for user files). But I cannot see that it makes a difference.

Comment: You changed the location of the DLL. Did you update the LibraryDirectory?

Comment: I did and then moved to using the default directories so I no longer needed the the directories. Im writing up a solution that I got to work. It required loading the library from the c script because he script doesnt recognize that modelica had loaded the dll.. Its not an ideal solution but im not sure there is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing compiled library headers from c-scripts that are called by a Modelica external function call is possible.

However, it is still not determined if there is an efficient method to access the .dll. This is discussed in a follow up question [External Functions: Alternative Method to use .dll from a C-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187064/external-functions-alternative-method-to-use-dll-from-a-c-script).

The solution that allowed the header files to be recognized is presented. Thanks to all who responded in helping figure this out.

---

**Step 1) Create Folder Structure**

Modelica looks in default directories automatically for external function dependencies. Section 12.9.4 of [modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33Revision1.pdf](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33Revision1.pdf)

The default location that Modelica looks for compiled libraries is a folder called `Library` within the Resources folder of your project:

`LibraryDirectory="modelica://LibraryPackageName/Resources/Library"`

For header files and c-scripts the default location is a folder called `Include` within the Resources folder of your project:

`IncludeDirectory="modelica://LibraryPackageName/Resources/Include"`

To specify alternative directories follow the modelica spec document. As of Modelica Specification 3.3 Rev 1 you can only specify one `LibraryDirectory` and one `IncludeDirectory`. Though this may be addressed in the future  https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/2103.

Summary of Overall Folder Structure
[image: Required Folder Structure]

**Step 2) Create Modelica Function and C-Scripts in locations specified in above image**

Below are examples that can be used for reference.

*Modelica Function*

```
function chirp

  input Modelica.SIunits.AngularVelocity w_start;
  input Modelica.SIunits.AngularVelocity w_end;
  input Real A;
  input Real M;
  input Real t;
  output Real u "output signal";

  external "C" u=chirp(w_start,w_end,A,M,t)
    annotation(Library="libgsl",Include="#include \"chirp.c\"");

end chirp;
```

*C-Script*

```
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

double chirp(double w1, double w2, double A, double M, double time)
{
  double res;
  res=A*cos(w1*time+(w2-w1)*time*time/(2*M));
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can only be resolved with relative include paths or future tools that implement future Modelica Language Specification 3.4. See https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/2103 for the corresponding update on the Modelica Language Specification.

Comment: I had read that ticket before and I'm not quite sure that my problem and that issue are the same thing. I've attempted to put things in the same directory and things still didn't work which I think is what that ticket is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You set include directory to `modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/gsl-1.8/`
and then use `#include <gsl-1.8/gsl/gsl_errno.h>`

Do you really have a directory gsl-1.8 in the directory gsl-1.8 (some projects have such a structure - but it is generally rare)? If that is not the case change to `#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>`.

I believe hierarchical includes are also searched in the path and thus that should work; otherwise you could always set includeDirectory to `modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/gsl-1.8/gsl` and use `#include <gsl_errno.h>`.

Comment: No there is not a directory gsl-1.8 within gsl-1.8. I set the library directory to `modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/gsl-1.8/`. The include directory is `modelica://ExternalFuncTest/Resources/Source/` so that the c-script is picked up. That's why I added the `gsl-1.8` to the header in the hope that it would look in the Source folder for `gsl-1.8` and then `gsl/gsl_errno.h`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that it was libraries in source. I believe there is another simpler solution - will just verify

Comment: I changed the location of the gsl header folder and it works now. I'll update my post with what I found. I'm still curious what your approach was though. Do you know what the default Library and Include directories are or where it is specified? I can't seem to locate it in the modelica spec.

Comment: Defaults are: modelica://LibraryName/Resources/Include and modelica://LibraryName/Resources/Library from 12.9.4 in https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33Revision1.pdf

Comment: Now the header issue is settled I'm trying now call a function from the dll (which was the whole reason the header thing happened). I added an update to the original question. Could you please take a look at it?